# Ubuntu Touch / Meizu MX4 : Camera not working after OTA4 install

Tags: ubuntu-touch, meizu-mx4

Has someone encountered this kind of problem? I tried to uninstall and reinstall the Camera app but nothing better.

Comment: I used this shell command line on a terminal from an Ubuntu Desktop computer to restore OTA3 on the phone :

ubuntu-device-flash --revision=3 touch --device=arale --channel=ubuntu-touch/stable/meizu.en

Answer (score 0):

If not, you can check in System Settings - Security and Privacy - Other application accesses - Camera, and confirm if the check item for Camera is ticked. For me worked (mx4).